# Blank Screen on Preview Sencha Architect 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I created a project and on the first preview it's showing blank screen, a simple project, with no codes, only this steps in sequence:

I only add two Form Panels, named them, created add two buttons on mainPanel, and them created NavigationView and linked mainPanel on MainNav (NavigationView).

[Here my project on Deposit Files to Download](http://depositfiles.org/files/efe5hgxlg)